# VB.NET Class Library dll.config File

Tags: vb.net

My question is on config files, or dll.config for a class library project (dll).  Does the dll have to be compiled for the changes in the config file to take affect?

The problem I've noticed is that I add a reference to another solution to my dll, and it still has a connection string that points to the test database, even though I've updated it in the config file.

If it does have to be compiled, what's the point of having a config file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DLL's (Class Libraries) don't use config files.  You'll need to set the configuration data via the application's config file.

You could, if you really want to, have a class library use a config file, but I don't think that's best practice and kind of defeats the purpose of the class library, IMO.

Comment: In my debug folder, I have DocDb2Model.dll and DocDb2Model.dll.config.  It looks like the .config file is one VS created from the Settings I added in the project settings.  The problem I'm having is that when I make a change in the .config file it does not seem to take affect.

Comment: I agree. As a best practice I would suggest having the .exe be responsible for reading the config file and pass any required information (e.g. connection strings, folder paths, etc.) to the dll as a method parameter.

Comment: That's odd - I'm not sure why you have a config file at all.  Class Library's don't come with them unless you add them yourself, IME.  Even if the config file is there, it's not going to be used by the DLL.

Comment: @Tim.  I didn't manually create the config file.  Visual Studio created it.

Comment: @user842818 - didn't say you did, just that in my experience I've only seen them when they were added.  Regardless of how it got there, my answer and ChrisNel52's atill stand - your DLL is *not* going to use it.

Comment: @Tim - Then what's the point of using the Settings under project settings in VS for a class library program?  I always thought the benefit was so changes could be made there that wouldn't require a recompile.

Comment: @user842818 - A class library is intended to be a chunk of reusable code that can be used by potentially many different applications.  Putting configuration or settings in there is self-defeating.  The application should set those kinds of items, and as already pointed out the class library will read the calling application's config file.

Comment: Ok thanks.  The only thing I need to do then is move my connection string to the application from the DLL.  Since my DLL is responsible for all database calls, what would be the best approach to get the connection string from the application?  I really don't want to resort to using a Singleton.

Comment: No reason to use a singleton here.  No reason for the application to explicitly give the DLL the connection string.  All the application needs to have is the connetion string in it's config file - the DLL can read the application's config file and get the connection string.

Comment: @Tim - Without knowing what application I would be using, how could I reference the application's connection string setting to the DLL?

Comment: You're not referencing anything to the DLL.  You're simply storing settings in the application's config file, and the application is then using the DLL - the DLL will know to read the application's config file.  This is getting away from your original question, so if you're still confused it'd be better to open another question, IMO - rather than having a long conversation in the comments section.

Answer (score 3):

You need to copy the config elements form the App.config of the DLL to the config file of the application that is referencing the DLL. If you reference the DLL in a WebApp then you need to copy the elements to the web.config. If you reference in the WinApp then you need to make sure that the WinApp has a config file and copy the elements to that file.

Answer (score 1):

No, the dll does not have to be compiled for your config changes to take affect.

If your dll file reads from a config file (app.config or web.config), than it will read the config file of the executable that is referencing it.

Comment: As Chris mentioned, your DLL is reading from the config file of the application that is referencing it.  .NET DLLs don't read from their own config files.

Comment: Does Visual Studio detects DLL config files and include them in the application's config file?